# Кодирование строки через urlencode

Tags: кодировка, php

Здравствуйте.

Пишу скрипт интернет магазина, и возникла ситуация.
В каталоге будет несколько фильтров, и нужно чтобы значение этих фильтров были также в адресной строке, и эти строки нужно закодировать так чтобы браузер корректно с ними работал.

Исходная строка в кодировке UTF-8:         **+/DVB-T2, DVB-C**
Строка закодированная через urlencode:      **%2B%2FDVB-T2%2C+DVB-C**
Строка закодированная через rawurlencode:  **%2B%2FDVB-T2%2C%20DVB-C**
Строка сгенерировання через сервис http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/ : **%252B%252FDVB-T2%252C%2BDVB-C**

Из всех перечисленных работает только последний. Все остальные отдают 404 ошибку, возможно из-за того что некоторые символы не кодируються.

Как исправить эту ситуацию ?

Спасибо.

Comment: > Строка сгенерировання через сервис

Эквивалентна варианту номер два: `%2B%2FDVB-T2%2C%20DVB-C`. Это если ее два раза прогнать, то она еще и символы процента закодирует.

> кодируються

[tsya.ru](http://tsya.ru)

> Все остальные отдают 404 ошибку

Сервера или скрипта? Что скрипт получает? Если строка генерируется на сервере, то в каком виде она появляется на странице пользователя?

Comment: Это фильтры, в каталоге товаров. Выбирают тип тюнера (прим: +/DVB-T2, DVB-C ). И этот фильтр добавляеться в адресную строку и получается что то типа http://site.ru/catalog/zhk-televizory/1/890:%2B%2FDVB-T2%2C+DVB-C;/ И тут вместо 32 может быть любое значение.